# Micronaut HttpClient with keystore and sslcontext

Tags: java, micronaut

I am trying to access third party API which required to use keystore with sslcontext.
We're using `io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient` to access a 3rd party API.
How to create HttpClient with keystore and sslcontext in micronaut?

Comment: Can you show us how you're doing this without Micronaut?